# Cannot expose simple API using Docker container and FastAPI

Tags: python, docker, api, fastapi

I have a simple API with the following tree structure:

```
.
├── api
│   ├── fast.py
│   └── __init__.py
├── Dockerfile
├── Makefile
└── requirements.txt
```

The contents of `fast.py` are as follows:

```
from fastapi import FastAPI
from fastapi.middleware.cors import CORSMiddleware
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def index():
    return {"greeting": "Hello world!!!!!!!!!!!!!!"}

@app.get("/predict")
def predict():
    # create a datetime object from the user provided datetime
    return {'cool': True}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8000)
```

The contents of the `Dockerfile` are as follows:

```
FROM python:3.8.6-buster

COPY api /api
COPY requirements.txt /requirements.txt

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

CMD uvicorn api.fast:app --host 0.0.0.0 --port $PORT
```

When I start the API on my localhost in my Windows machine using `wsl`, it works fine, and I can access my API:

```
# uvicorn api.fast:app --reload                                             
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [20733] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [20770]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
INFO:     127.0.0.1:40446 - "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 OK
```

However, when I try to access it from within a Docker container, I have issues. First I build the image as follows:

`docker build --tag=docker_api_example .`

then I run a container as follows:

`docker run -it -e PORT=8000 -p 8000:8000 docker_api_example sh`

The container opens up and I run the same `uvicorn` command again:

```
# uvicorn api.fast:app --reload
```

The process appears to start with no issues:

```
INFO:     Uvicorn running on http://127.0.0.1:8000 (Press CTRL+C to quit)
INFO:     Started reloader process [8] using statreload
INFO:     Started server process [10]
INFO:     Waiting for application startup.
INFO:     Application startup complete.
```

However, when I navigate to `http://127.0.0.1:8000` on my browser I get an error:

[image]

Why does this occur and how can I fix it?

Comment: Is the port mapping of 8000 correct

Comment: There is a difference between running on `127.0.0.1` and `0.0.0.0` and from your description it's not clear what you are actually doing (Your `CMD` has `--host 0.0.0.0` and then the logs show `127.0.0.1`). There's a nice explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59182290/1561148) by [David Maze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10008173/david-maze).

Comment: In your `docker run` command, you're running `sh` instead of the (correct) `uvicorn --host 0.0.0.0`   Try taking the `sh` off the end of that command.