# running sbt project from inside docker container

Tags: docker, scala, sbt

I have a project that when running locally, outputs `server started at /127.0.0.1:5000` and I can access it locally on the said port just fine.

I am trying to run it through docker. I have the following:

`DockerFile`:

```
FROM mozilla/sbt

ADD build.sbt /root/build/
RUN cd /root/build && sbt compile

EXPOSE 5000
WORKDIR /root/build

CMD sbt run
```

and the following `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  sbt:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: ./Dockerfile
    image: sbt
    ports:
      - "8080:5000"
    volumes:
      - "./:/root/build"
```

I try running it through `docker-compose up` and I can see the logs about the server starting, but can't access the service through the specified port, namely `8080`. Am I missing something?

fyi, the above setup is inspired by this [post](https://jrtechs.net/java/running-scala-code-in-docker) where I have changed the base image and also got rid of the `external-network` bit that I did not understand.

Comment: Adding the build.sbt may help someone reproduce this. Can you access it when you build and run using just the Dockerfile?

Comment: trying to figure out how to mount a volume when running straight from the dockerfile. it doesn't like it: `docker run -it -v "./:/root/build" $(docker build -q .) `

Comment: Anything that outputs "server started at 127.0.0.1:5000" probably won't be reachable from outside Docker.  You don't say anything about what the process in the container is (presumably something Scala-based) but setting it to listen on 0.0.0.0 might make inter-container communication and the `ports:` setting work.  See also for example [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).

Comment: bravo @DavidMaze that did it :) do you want to post it as an answer, or should I post an answer myself?

Answer (score 0):

If app starts by default on port 5000, bu you need to start it in another port with docker you should use:

```
ports:
      - "8080:5000"
```

Internally your app continues using the 5000 port but docker bind that port to another, in the example : 8080

Comment: ah good catch. I always used the same port so got the order wrong. I made the change you suggested, stopped the server, ran `docker compose up` again and tried accessing `http://localhost:8080/foo/bar` but no joy. (updated the question body)

Comment: #1 is the app running? #2 do you have a error log? #3 enter to the container `docker exec -it myapp bash` and then execute `curl localhost:5000/foo/bar` if not works,, the problem is with your app , not with docker

Comment: yeah I can successfully hit that endpoint from inside the container. :/

Comment: are you on windows? attach the curl localhost:8080/foo/bar -v log or compare it with the internal curl

Comment: on mac. im getting: 

```
curl http://localhost:8080/foo/bar -v
*   Trying ::1...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /foo/bar HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8080
> User-Agent: curl/7.54.0
> Accept: */*
> 
* Empty reply from server
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

internal curl gives me the json response.

Comment: I even tried `docker-compose up --force-recreate` to make sure there is no weird caching going on. still the same issue.