# Running an application via docker container on http://localhost:8000/ returns Bad Request, but http://127.0.0.1:8000/ works

Tags: python, django, docker, containers, docker-desktop

Disclaimer: I am a docker noob and I'm trying to learn. I am also running this on Windows 10

Here's my `Dockerfile.yaml`

```
FROM python:3.11
# setup env variables
ENV PYTHONBUFFERED=1
ENV DockerHOME=/app/django-app
# Expose port
EXPOSE 8000
# create work dir
RUN mkdir -p $DockerHOME
# set work dir
WORKDIR $DockerHOME
# copy code to work dir
COPY . $DockerHOME
# install dependencies
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
# move working dir to where manage.py is
WORKDIR $DockerHOME/flag_games
# set default command (I thinkk)
ENTRYPOINT ["python"]
# run commands for app to run
CMD ["manage.py", "collectstatic", "--noinput"]
CMD ["manage.py", "runserver", "0.0.0.0:8000"]
```

Here are the commands I use (I run `make docker-build` and `make docker-run`)

```
docker-build:
    docker build --tag docker-django .

docker-run:
     docker run -d -p 8000:8000 --name flag-game docker-django
```

My container runs fine

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Admin\Projects\flag-games> docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE           COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                    NAMES
175c38b4ea9e   docker-django   "python manage.py ru…"   26 minutes ago   Up 26 minutes   0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   flag-game
```

When I try to hit the website I get:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Admin\Projects\flag-games> curl.exe -v localhost:8000
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...                                            
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:8000
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
< Date: Sun, 23 Apr 2023 06:16:31 GMT
< Server: WSGIServer/0.2 CPython/3.11.3
< Content-Type: text/html
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Referrer-Policy: same-origin
< Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin
< Connection: close
<

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bad Request (400)</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Bad Request (400)</h1><p></p>
</body>
</html>
* Closing connection 0
```

Even worse for `0.0.0.0:8000`

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\Admin\Projects\flag-games> curl.exe -v 0.0.0.0:8000  
*   Trying 0.0.0.0:8000...
* connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8000 failed: Address not available
* Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 0.0.0.0 port 8000 after 0 ms: Couldn't connect to server
```

but `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` works fine.

```
 curl.exe -v http://127.0.0.1:8000/
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* Connected to 127.0.0.1 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8000
> User-Agent: curl/8.0.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
```

Am I misunderstanding how docker works? and how all the ports/network communicates with each other?

EDIT: Adding part of`settings.py`

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['127.0.0.1', '0.0.0.0']

# Application definition
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'world_flags.apps.WorldFlagsConfig',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    "whitenoise.runserver_nostatic",
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]


MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"
ROOT_URLCONF = 'flag_games.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'flag_games.wsgi.application'
```

Comment: Since you are getting HTTP responses, you are successfully connecting to the container and the Docker-level wiring is correct.  Docker problems tend to look more like "connection refused" or "connection reset by peer" errors that don't get as far as returning an HTTP status code.

Comment: Okay, so things are going as expected? Does that mean the docker container port is useless to connect to?

Comment: The Docker-level setup seems to be okay (a couple of oddities in the Dockerfile but nothing that would obviously cause this), which would suggest that a [mcve] needs to include enough of your application code to demonstrate the issue.  Can you [edit] the question to include this?

Comment: I've added part of my `settings.py` which I assume is what is needed

Answer (score -1):

Mike, localhost, and 127.0.0.1 are not the same.

A very good explanation I found on Stackoverflow:

[Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip)

[From inside of a Docker container, how do I connect to the localhost of the machine?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24319662/from-inside-of-a-docker-container-how-do-i-connect-to-the-localhost-of-the-mach)

This will solve your query. Hope this helps.

Comment: Okay, so the docker container port is useless for me?