# Access gRPC python server with "localhost" security in WSL2 docker from windows

Tags: python, docker, grpc, wsl-2

The issue is this. I am getting a zip file made by pyinstaller. Inside the file there is a setting making the server listen only to localhost `server.add_insecure_port(f'localhost:{port_num}')`. I want to run this python file from a centos docker. Docker is running on WSL2.

So far I was able to run the docker but the issue is as follow: I can make grpcUrl calls to localhost:port from the WSL2 (in my case ubunty). But when I try to make those calls from windows cmd I get the following error:

`Failed to dial target host "localhost:9111": dial tcp [::1]:9111: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`
Or this `Failed to dial target host "127.0.0.1:9111": dial tcp 127.0.0.1:9111: connectex: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.`

I have started the docker using `--network="host"` hoping it can help me, but it only help ubuntu to do grpcUrl calls, but not windows.

Any help would be appriciated. Note that I cannot change localhost to 0.0.0.0...

Comment: You need to change `localhost` to `0.0.0.0`; see for example [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).  Can you make the relevant change in the application (consider adding a command-line option and/or environment variable) and rerun the pyinstaller packager?

Comment: @DavidMaze as I told before because of security reasons the package cannot be changed to 0.0.0.0 and this is not an option.
Is there an option to for example add a proxy in the wsl machine that will transfer all tcp calls to localhost, and making it "internal calls" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SSH tunneling was an answer for me.

Install SSH server on WSL:

1. `sudo apt install openssh-server`
2. `sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config` -> insert next block at the end

> ```
> Port 2222
> ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
> PubkeyAuthentication no
> PasswordAuthentication yes
> ```

search for any additional `PasswordAuthentication` in the file and make it `yes`.

3. Create ssh key

> ```
> sudo ssh-keygen -A
> sudo service ssh --full-restart
> ```

4. Add a script to run SSH on startup `vi ~/.bashrc` -> insert next block at the end of the file

> ```
> #Start ssh automatically
> RUNNING=`ps aux | grep sshd | grep -v grep`
> if [ -z "$RUNNING" ]; then
>     sudo service ssh start > /dev/null 2>&1 &
>     disown
> fi
> ```

5. Make ssh server run without password `sudo visudo` -> insert next code at the end of the file

> ```
> %sudo ALL=NOPASSWD: /usr/sbin/service ssh *
> ```

6. Restart WSL -> from CMD run `wsl --shutdown` and open wsl again (for example by running ubuntu)

Get the ip of the wsl - run from CMD `wsl hostname -I`

Now run from CMD `ssh -L 127.0.0.1:<port>:localhost:<port> <wsl username>@<ip from wsl hostname -I> -p 2222`