# Unable to get the Docker port mapping right

Tags: docker, dockerfile, containers

I am a newbie in Docker, just. following some tutorial, and tried to dockerize a simple dotnet core 7 rest api app, which listens to http://localhost:5206.
Everything looks ok, when I try to do the build steps from inside the base ubuntu image. Even Docker build also succeeds, even docker run also succeeds.
But I am not able to access the app from host no matter what I try:

**I am on Mac 12.6:**

**Dockerfile:**

```
`FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update
RUN  apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0
RUN apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-7.0
RUN apt-get install -y git
COPY /helloWorld/ /app
WORKDIR  /app
EXPOSE   5206
ENTRYPOINT dotnet run --project helloWorld.csproj`
```

**Build Output:**

```
`[+] Building 0.1s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                                                                                            
 => [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                                                     
 => => transferring dockerfile: 524B                                                                                                                                                     
 => [internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                                                        
 => => transferring context: 2B                                                                                                                                                          
 => [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/ubuntu:latest                                                                                                                         
 => [1/7] FROM docker.io/library/ubuntu                                                                                                                                                  
 => [internal] load build context                                                                                                                                                        
 => => transferring context: 4.26kB                                                                                                                                                      
 => CACHED [2/7] RUN apt-get update                                                                                                                                                      
 => CACHED [3/7] RUN  apt-get install -y dotnet-sdk-7.0                                                                                                                                 
 => CACHED [4/7] RUN apt-get install -y aspnetcore-runtime-7.0                                                                                                                           
 => CACHED [5/7] RUN apt-get install -y git                                                                                                                                              
 => CACHED [6/7] COPY /helloWorld/ /app                                                                                                                                                  
 => CACHED [7/7] WORKDIR  /app                                                                                                                                                           
 => exporting to image                                                                                                                                                                   
 => => exporting layers                                                                                                                                                                  
 => => writing image sha256:9de0bdec1be190f4bde20e211a746f3a813353dca1124b849086f18ef0437312                                                                                             
 => => naming to docker.io/dotnet/api/1 `
```

**Run Command:**

```
`docker run  -p 127.0.0.1:8080:5206 9de0bdec1be1`
```

**Output:**

```
`Welcome to .NET 7.0!
---------------------
SDK Version: 7.0.105

----------------
Installed an ASP.NET Core HTTPS development certificate.
To trust the certificate run 'dotnet dev-certs https --trust' (Windows and macOS only).
Learn about HTTPS: https://aka.ms/dotnet-https
----------------
Write your first app: https://aka.ms/dotnet-hello-world
Find out what's new: https://aka.ms/dotnet-whats-new
Explore documentation: https://aka.ms/dotnet-docs
Report issues and find source on GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/core
Use 'dotnet --help' to see available commands or visit: https://aka.ms/dotnet-cli
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Building...
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5206
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app`
```

Now trying to access http//:127.0.0.1:8080 or http://localhost:8080 from my Mac's chrome browser results in 'Site cant be reached'

**Inspect output:**

```
`[
    {
        "Id": "baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224",
        "Created": "2023-06-11T02:34:22.251278271Z",
        "Path": "/bin/sh",
        "Args": [
            "-c",
            "dotnet run --project helloWorld.csproj"
        ],
        "State": {
            "Status": "running",
            "Running": true,
            "Paused": false,
            "Restarting": false,
            "OOMKilled": false,
            "Dead": false,
            "Pid": 94955,
            "ExitCode": 0,
            "Error": "",
            "StartedAt": "2023-06-11T02:34:22.511203476Z",
            "FinishedAt": "0001-01-01T00:00:00Z"
        },
        "Image": "sha256:9de0bdec1be190f4bde20e211a746f3a813353dca1124b849086f18ef0437312",
        "ResolvConfPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224/resolv.conf",
        "HostnamePath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224/hostname",
        "HostsPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224/hosts",
        "LogPath": "/var/lib/docker/containers/baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224/baef637d76ec08644cef9e642938d3912719267d1eb3adb6f6debbc7f6cd6224-json.log",
        "Name": "/reverent_cohen",
        "RestartCount": 0,
        "Driver": "overlay2",
        "Platform": "linux",
        "MountLabel": "",
        "ProcessLabel": "",
        "AppArmorProfile": "",
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {
                "Type": "json-file",
                "Config": {}
            },
            "NetworkMode": "default",
            "PortBindings": {
**                "5206/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }**
                ]
            },
            "RestartPolicy": {
                "Name": "no",
                "MaximumRetryCount": 0
            },
            "AutoRemove": false,
            "VolumeDriver": "",
            "VolumesFrom": null,
            "ConsoleSize": [
                53,
                190
            ],
            "CapAdd": null,
            "CapDrop": null,
            "CgroupnsMode": "private",
            "Dns": [],
            "DnsOptions": [],
            "DnsSearch": [],
            "ExtraHosts": null,
            "GroupAdd": null,
            "IpcMode": "private",
            "Cgroup": "",
            "Links": null,
            "OomScoreAdj": 0,
            "PidMode": "",
            "Privileged": false,
            "PublishAllPorts": false,
            "ReadonlyRootfs": false,
            "SecurityOpt": null,
            "UTSMode": "",
            "UsernsMode": "",
            "ShmSize": 67108864,
            "Runtime": "runc",
            "Isolation": "",
            "CpuShares": 0,
            "Memory": 0,
            "NanoCpus": 0,
            "CgroupParent": "",
            "BlkioWeight": 0,
            "BlkioWeightDevice": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteBps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceReadIOps": [],
            "BlkioDeviceWriteIOps": [],
            "CpuPeriod": 0,
            "CpuQuota": 0,
            "CpuRealtimePeriod": 0,
            "CpuRealtimeRuntime": 0,
            "CpusetCpus": "",
            "CpusetMems": "",
            "Devices": [],
            "DeviceCgroupRules": null,
            "DeviceRequests": null,
            "MemoryReservation": 0,
            "MemorySwap": 0,
            "MemorySwappiness": null,
            "OomKillDisable": null,
            "PidsLimit": null,
            "Ulimits": null,
            "CpuCount": 0,
            "CpuPercent": 0,
            "IOMaximumIOps": 0,
            "IOMaximumBandwidth": 0,
            "MaskedPaths": [
                "/proc/asound",
                "/proc/acpi",
                "/proc/kcore",
                "/proc/keys",
                "/proc/latency_stats",
                "/proc/timer_list",
                "/proc/timer_stats",
                "/proc/sched_debug",
                "/proc/scsi",
                "/sys/firmware"
            ],
            "ReadonlyPaths": [
                "/proc/bus",
                "/proc/fs",
                "/proc/irq",
                "/proc/sys",
                "/proc/sysrq-trigger"
            ]
        },
        "GraphDriver": {
            "Data": {
                "LowerDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85b0df60bdcf8d34a5d2896f26e10dd46ed896520e72fc4d4420da001a738956-init/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/owr15a3kq6meankosw96l2stv/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/fto2qe2rhicv7anktmku3bh3i/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/qohre7sxyinw4iki1le0vymfz/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/iezfa6seuu9k27cdtjyehvn4d/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/u5f34z9qtne9sfomvl6j5wnw2/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/rb61ba4hwhzq00qmzeftqdipp/diff:/var/lib/docker/overlay2/e330dc80a6050f494584fe2311e31862c8ce98d6392fa58c1c231b943c28a693/diff",
                "MergedDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85b0df60bdcf8d34a5d2896f26e10dd46ed896520e72fc4d4420da001a738956/merged",
                "UpperDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85b0df60bdcf8d34a5d2896f26e10dd46ed896520e72fc4d4420da001a738956/diff",
                "WorkDir": "/var/lib/docker/overlay2/85b0df60bdcf8d34a5d2896f26e10dd46ed896520e72fc4d4420da001a738956/work"
            },
            "Name": "overlay2"
        },
        "Mounts": [],
        "Config": {
            "Hostname": "baef637d76ec",
            "Domainname": "",
            "User": "",
            "AttachStdin": false,
            "AttachStdout": true,
            "AttachStderr": true,
            "ExposedPorts": {
                "5206/tcp": {}
            },
            "Tty": false,
            "OpenStdin": false,
            "StdinOnce": false,
            "Env": [
                "PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
            ],
            "Cmd": null,
            "Image": "9de0bdec1be1",
            "Volumes": null,
            "WorkingDir": "/app",
            "Entrypoint": [
                "/bin/sh",
                "-c",
                "dotnet run --project helloWorld.csproj"
            ],
            "OnBuild": null,
            "Labels": {
                "org.opencontainers.image.ref.name": "ubuntu",
                "org.opencontainers.image.version": "22.04"
            }
        },
        "NetworkSettings": {
            "Bridge": "",
            "SandboxID": "df620ef8f9b0f094344c87ba6511a7bfc90587566cc905418e39b91d526e4a97",
            "HairpinMode": false,
            "LinkLocalIPv6Address": "",
            "LinkLocalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
**            "Ports": {
                "5206/tcp": [
                    {
                        "HostIp": "127.0.0.1",
                        "HostPort": "8080"
                    }
                ]
            }**,
            "SandboxKey": "/var/run/docker/netns/df620ef8f9b0",
            "SecondaryIPAddresses": null,
            "SecondaryIPv6Addresses": null,
            "EndpointID": "7fa795a95fafad9ec1f1ad835edc3337758ce99e6630f6b04ee99d0731d4e315",
            "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
            "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
            "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
            "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
            "IPPrefixLen": 16,
            "IPv6Gateway": "",
            "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
            "Networks": {
                "bridge": {
                    "IPAMConfig": null,
                    "Links": null,
                    "Aliases": null,
                    "NetworkID": "8df8403af0189a1f4ca71732d675d7533e48035088d754bfdb6088046f44ead2",
                    "EndpointID": "7fa795a95fafad9ec1f1ad835edc3337758ce99e6630f6b04ee99d0731d4e315",
                    "Gateway": "172.17.0.1",
                    "IPAddress": "172.17.0.2",
                    "IPPrefixLen": 16,
                    "IPv6Gateway": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6Address": "",
                    "GlobalIPv6PrefixLen": 0,
                    "MacAddress": "02:42:ac:11:00:02",
                    "DriverOpts": null
                }
            }
        }
    }
]`
```

OR:

```
% docker ps
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED          STATUS          PORTS                      NAMES
baef637d76ec   9de0bdec1be1   "/bin/sh -c 'dotnet …"   27 seconds ago   Up 26 seconds   127.0.0.1:8080->5206/tcp   reverent_cohen
```

I can clearly see ports are mapped, but not sure why it doesnot work, other run configuration I tried:

```
docker  run -p 80:5206 9de0bdec1be1   
docker  run -p 5206:5206 9de0bdec1be1
```

Each time I can see the ports are mapped in NetworkSettings section of inspect, but with same results. Also I am sure ports used for host are all available(8080,  80, 5206)

What am I doing wrong, is there anything else to check in the inspect? Frustrateted that I am stuck in this basic step preventing me to move to next topic in my learning path,  please help.

```
docker run -d -p 127.0.0.1:80:5206 9de0bdec1be1
docker  run -p 80:5206 9de0bdec1be1   
docker  run -p 5206:5206 9de0bdec1be1
```

Was expecting to able to access the app from host's(Mac) web browser.

Note each time I try a new run config, I stop the previous running container.

```
% docker ps                                
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE     COMMAND   CREATED   STATUS    PORTS     NAMES
%
```

Comment: Try making your application inside the container listen on 0.0.0.0:5206.

Comment: Also see for example [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).

Comment: Will try this out.

Answer (score 0):

In your config I see empty property for 5206 port, That ia one area to look for possible config mistake.

```
*"ExposedPorts": {
                "5206/tcp": {}
            },*
```

Another thing is, is your project really running and delivering a response? can you try to connect to the container and find a way to check this before testing on your browser?

Best!
Makanist

Comment: Will have to check this, it's strange that expose port is empty, though in dockerfile I did mention it, app is most likely running, as we can see the startup message

Comment: its running: 
docker exec -it 405b6ca47d26 curl -X 'GET' 'http://localhost:5206/WeatherForecast' -H 'accept: text/plain' 
[{"date":"2023-06-15","temperatureC":18,"temperatureF":64,"summary":"Warm"},{"date":"2023-06-16","temperatureC":35,"temperatureF":94,"summary":"Freezing"},{"date":"2023-06-17","temperatureC":44,"temperatureF":111,"summary":"Bracing"},{"date":"2023-06-18","temperatureC":5,"temperatureF":40,"summary":"Scorching"},{"date":"2023-06-19","temperatureC":-2,"temperatureF":29,"summary":"Warm"}]%

Comment: cool! can you provide here what changes you made it to work?

Answer (score 0):

You can provide the actual ip address of your machine in the run command, e.g.:

```
docker run -p actual_ip_address:8080:5206
```

And then access the url `http://actual_ip_address:8080/`

Comment: Oh cool... will let you know

Comment: http://192.168.0.125:8080/WeatherForecast didnot work