# Docker container localhost not exposed

Tags: docker, go, containers, go-gin

When starting a gin server, I was using `router.Run("localhost:8080")`.

Afterwards, running the docker command `docker run -p 8080:8080 <IMAGE_NAME>` does not expose the service to my local machine.

It only worked after I changed it to `router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")`. Is there a difference between `localhost` and `0.0.0.0`? If so, what is the difference in context of a docker container?

I am expecting that `localhost` is the same as `0.0.0.0` as that is the behaviour on my local machine during development.

My main function is below

```golang
func main() {
    fmt.Println("hello world")

    router := gin.Default()

    router.Use(middlewares.CORSMiddleware())
    router.POST("/api/notify", notify.NotifyHandler)

    // router.Run("localhost:8080")
    router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")
}
```

Comment: Kindly post your code so that we can understand where the problem is. Ideally local host should hit.

Comment: did this helps you to understood the difference between `localhost` and `0.0.0.` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20778771/what-is-the-difference-between-0-0-0-0-127-0-0-1-and-localhost and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip

Comment: code posted as requested. But i think the answer below makes sense if it is correct :)

Comment: `localhost` is defined as `127.0.0.1` which is the container-private loopback interface; if you only bind to `127.0.0.1` then the process won't be reachable from outside its container.  Listening to `0.0.0.0` means "all interfaces" which is pretty much required in Docker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of networking, there is a significant difference between `localhost` and `0.0.0.0`, especially when dealing with Docker containers.

- **localhost:** When you use `localhost` as the host in your code (e.g., `router.Run("localhost:8080")`), the server will only listen for incoming connections on the loopback interface of the container. This means that the server will only be accessible from within the container itself, but not from the host machine or any external devices.
- **0.0.0.0:** When you use `0.0.0.0` as the host (e.g., `router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")`), the server will listen for incoming connections on all available network interfaces, including the loopback interface as well as any external network interfaces. This makes the server accessible not only from within the container but also from the host machine and external devices.

In the context of a Docker container, using `localhost` only makes the service available within the container itself. If you want to expose the service to the host machine or other devices, you need to use `0.0.0.0`.

When you run a Docker container with the `-p` option (e.g., `docker run -p 8080:8080 <IMAGE_NAME>`), you are binding a port on the host machine to a port in the container. In this case, the syntax `-p HOST_PORT:CONTAINER_PORT` indicates that any incoming traffic to the host's `HOST_PORT` will be forwarded to the container's `CONTAINER_PORT`.

So, if you use `router.Run("0.0.0.0:8080")`, the server in the container listens on all interfaces and accepts incoming connections from the host's `8080` port, which is then forwarded to the container's `8080` port.

In summary, the key difference is that `0.0.0.0` allows you to expose your service beyond the container's boundary, making it accessible from the host machine and other devices, while `localhost` confines the service to the container itself.

Comment: sounds very chatgpt haha but understood thanks

Comment: So what's the way out? Can it be used?