# Angular application running in a container not accessible from the browser

Tags: angular, docker, containers

My Angular application is running in a docker container but is not accessible from the browser:

I used port mapping as well:

`docker run -p 4200:4200 myhub/frontend`

Output:

```
** Angular Live Development Server is listening on localhost:4200, open your browser on http://localhost:4200/ **


✔ Compiled successfully.
✔ Browser application bundle generation complete.

5 unchanged chunks

Build at: 2023-10-01T15:22:15.153Z - Hash: b0fe0eaaee79f491 - Time: 142ms

✔ Compiled successfully.
```

Already tried different ports and image id as well like

```
docker run -p 8081:4200 myhub/frontend
docker run -p 81:4200 myhub/frontend
docker run -p 81:4200 8d6ab6afc575
```

Every time container starts successfully but cannot be accessed from the browser.

My simple docker file on my local laptop with Windows 11:

```
FROM node:18
WORKDIR /app
COPY package.json .
RUN npm install
COPY . .
CMD ["npm", "run", "start"]
```

Comment: can you share the dockerfile?

Comment: it is on your local machine or cloud?

Answer (score 1):

Probably your `npm start` command is executing `ng serve`.

Open the `package.json` file and change it to `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0` so you app can be reached outside the container at `localhost:4200`.

**Explanation**

127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and it refers to the current device we are on, the docker container so you can only listen it from inside the container. 0.0.0.0 is the reserved address to “all interfaces”. Everyone can listen to it. Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip) for a more detailed explanation

Comment: Everything is working locally

Comment: You mean the answer is good or no?

Comment: Changing to this `ng serve --host 0.0.0.0`  worked, thanks
But why do we need this???

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address and it refers to the current device we are on, the docker container so you can only listen it from inside the container. 0.0.0.0 is the reserved address to “all interfaces”. Everyone can listen to it.
Here a good explanation https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip