# How to run expo react native web with the production folder web-build?

Tags: react-native, docker, docker-compose, expo

I have dockerized a react native web. And I created the production folder in the root folder web-build with the command: `npx expo export:web`

And without docker. If I browse to the folder web-build and do a npx serve the app starts on url: `http://localhost:3000`

And I can build the image with the command `docker compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml build`.  So this I have for the dockerfile:

```
# pull base image

FROM node:lts-alpine


ARG NODE_ENV=production
ENV NODE_ENV $NODE_ENV


ARG PORT=19006
ENV PORT $PORT
EXPOSE $PORT 19001 19002


ENV NPM_CONFIG_PREFIX=/home/node/.npm-global
ENV PATH /home/node/.npm-global/bin:$PATH
RUN npm i --unsafe-perm --allow-root -g npm@latest expo-cli@latest

RUN mkdir /opt/dwl_frontend
WORKDIR /opt/dwl_frontend
ENV PATH /opt/dwl_frontend/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn
RUN yarn install


WORKDIR /opt/dwl_frontend

COPY ./ ./ 


ENTRYPOINT [ "npx", "serve" ]
```

But the problem I am facing is that if I run the image with: `docker compose -f docker-compose-prod.yml up`

then the app starts with url: `INFO  Accepting connections at http://localhost:19006`

But if I go to that url. I see the directory structure:

Index of  dwl_frontend/. And I see the content and folders of the root folder. But the actual app is not loading.

Question: how to run the docker container using the web-build folder?

Comment: `Accepting connections at localhost` usually means your application is only configured to listen on the container-private 127.0.0.1 loopback interface; it needs to listen on 0.0.0.0 all interfaces.  I don't see a specific question about `npx serve` but more generally see [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip).

Comment: @DavidMaze. This I don't understand. What I have to change in the dockerfile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using

```
npx serve web-build
```

So your entry point should look like this

```
ENTRYPOINT [ "npx", "serve", "web-build" ]
```