# Having a problem running a Flask app on docker

Tags: docker, flask, dockerfile, containers

This is the docker image I have created

```docker
FROM ubuntu:20.04

WORKDIR /app

COPY . /app 

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    apt-get install -y libgtk2.0-dev

RUN mkdir -p ~/miniconda3

RUN wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O miniconda.sh && \
    bash miniconda.sh -b -p /opt/miniconda && \
    rm miniconda.sh

ENV PATH /opt/miniconda/bin:$PATH

COPY environment.yaml /app/environment.yaml

RUN conda env create -f /app/environment.yaml

CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "source /opt/miniconda/etc/profile.d/conda.sh && conda activate my-env && python APIWrapper.py"]
```

When I run the docker image, the container is running successfully, but when I test the endpoint of the application it is not working properly,
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9whOU.png)

Starting the application:

```
$ docker run -p 5000:5000 sample-img:1.0
* Serving Flask app 'APIWrapper' (lazy loading)
...
* Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
```

Testing the application:

```
$ curl http://127.0.0.1:5000/extract?contractPath=/app/input/AWS.pdf
curl: (56) Recv failure: Connection reset by peer
```

Have tried using port mapping and mounting the volume containing my file but both aren't working

Comment: You shouldn't listen on local addresses

Comment: `Running on http://127.0.0.1...` means the application inside the container is configured in a way that it will be unreachable from outside its own container.  There are a couple of ways to configure the Flask dev server to listen on 0.0.0.0 instead, which are detailed in the linked question.

Answer (score -1):

To access your endpoint from outside your container, you must launch your app on the special host IP 0.0.0.0 and not 127.0.0.1 which is the IP to the running container and not the host machine.

cf [Docker app server ip address 127.0.0.1 difference of 0.0.0.0 ip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59179831/docker-app-server-ip-address-127-0-0-1-difference-of-0-0-0-0-ip)

Comment: Please flag this question as a duplicate, rather than leaving an answer that's just a link.  For Flask in particular there is a very specific question that discusses this case.